# Upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 6

Tags: npm, angular6, angular5

I am looking to upgrade from Angular 5 to Angular 6 on a particular web application.  We are unable to angular 8 at this time due to a dependency issue we've not been able to isolate (probably something deprecated and removed between 5 and 8).

The issue I have is the instruction sets I've seen to upgrade from angular 5 to angular 6 were written when angular 6 was the latest version, so they have things like

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
```

which if I did right now would try to upgrade to 8.0.2 (being the latest).

I guess I could try to upgrade with

```
npm install @angular/cli@6.2.9 -g
```

or similar, but that brings me into a nightmare of figuring out the versions for the whole suite of upgrades, which is going be a mighty PITA (especially since the guide [here](https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-6-4520e46c682b) has 29 different packages that are installed using @latest (not counting however many I will have to research that we use that are not part of that upgrade set).

Is there any resource that does this legwork for me already?  I'm guessing there's probably not, but you never know.

Our upgrade plan is to upgrade to 6 (to take advantage of some webpack changes and some tools that were written for 6+ to improve our build speed), and then rework everything on the deprecation list before an upgrade to 8.   However, we're to the point where we cannot hold off on the 6 upgrade until after we get the deprecation issues fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Although the migration process did not badly effect your project .It depends upon the **complexity** of web application.

Here is a useful link that can help you in migration https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0
https://medium.com/@filipjerga/angular-5-to-angular-6-migration-guide-7ba4d2544411